# Exponential distribution with a uniform parameter

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

The situation is that full rubbish bins are ready for collection at a rate of 2 per day in a given street.  That is, the number of bins ready for collection is a Poisson process with rate 2.  The bin lorry comes at day $T$, where $T$ ~ $U[6,8]$.  I wish to find the probability that there are no bins when the bus arrives.

I see two possible approaches to this question.  I can use the Poisson distribution $X$ ~ $Poi[2T]$ and find the probability $P(X = 0)$, or I can use the exponential distribution $Y$ ~ $Exp[2x]$ and find the probability $P(Y > T)$.

For the first option,

\begin{align}
P(X=0)& = (2T)^0 e^{-2T}\\
& = e^{-2T}
\end{align}

For with the second option,

\begin{align}
P(Y > T)& = 1 - P(Y < T)\\
& = 1 - (1-e^{-2T})\\
& = e^{-2T}
\end{align}
So I end up with the same expression for both approaches, which is reassuring, but I am not sure how to solve it, assuming that this is correct.  I am considering integrating over the range of t, that is

\begin{align}
\int_{6}^{8}e^{-2T}dT
\end{align}

Is this the correct way to solve the problem, or have I gone down completely the wrong track?

Comment: $$E(e^{-2T})=\int_6^8e^{-2t}\frac{dt}2$$

Comment: Could you explain what the intuition is of taking the expectation of that final expression?

Comment: Sorry, no intuition is required here, just the simplest application of the definitions. Additionally, note that $e^{-2T}$ is $P(X=0\mid T)=P(Y>T\mid T)$ and that $E(e^{-2T})$ is $P(X=0)=P(Y>T)$ but that $e^{-2T}$ is not $P(X=0)=P(Y>T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Conditioning on $T$, we may compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(T)=0) &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(N(T)=0\mid T=t)f_T(t)\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(N(t)=0)f_T(t)\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_6^8 \frac12 e^{-2t}\,\mathsf dt,
\end{align}
where $f_T(t) = \frac12\,\mathsf 1_{(6,8)}(t)$ is the density of $T$ and $\{N(t):t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is a Poisson process with rate $2$.

Comment: @Did I realize my notation may not be up to your standards, but this is a valid approach to solving the problem that yields the correct answer.